# Inductance of air core coil with small diameter

Tags: amplifier, antenna, inductance, coil

I have some legacy circuits with air core inductors (copper) w/ 19 turns, SWG = 24, dia = 3.20 mm, Length = 12 mm.  The measured inductance on a good instrument was 80nH/13.7 milliohms & 93nH/13.37 milliohms.

However, calculations show that it *should* be 272nH, using outer dia, and ~185nH using mean dia.

I need to replicate this board. But what value of L (also Q and C) to choose ?? This is a very simple board for an antenna amplifier for MW/SW/FM bands which works very well - gives > +20dB all the way from 500Khz upto 125MHz FLAT (based on simulations), and I don't want to mess it up.

What is the community opinion/ advice ?

Comment: Replace the "good" instrument or make a better calculation. You won't find any big help here.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  ah yes. So I infer that you agree the instrument was incorrect. I did too, was just placing all the information out there. Surprised about the 2nd half of your response tho'.

Comment: I meant, your problem has no answer: You have measured 80nH and 93nH, but you have calculated to be 272nH and 185nH, who can help you?

Comment: Measure SRF and then L, Q at 100MHz with a precision C

Comment: http://www.coilcraft.com/images/maxiq.gif

Comment: Why not just copy the dimensions exactly? You don't need to know what the inductance is. If you make an identical coil, it will have the same inductance. What is the "C" you are talking about?

Comment: Actually I want to replace the coil with a PCB etched one. Hence the need to know. The 'C' is the self capacitance.

Comment: If there is some conductor material in the proximity of the coil, the inductance becomes lower.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your meter is OK and that you are measuring the inductor on its own, the only explanation is that you haven't used a calculator that takes account of the parasitic capacitance between turns. The net parasitic capacitance can make your meter read an incorrect value of impedance and give a false impression that the inductance is smaller.

So, your inductor is likely to be 270 nH but, due to its parasitic capacitance and using a test frequency that is above the coils self resonant frequency, you get an incorrect reading.

Comment: Thank you Andy. That makes sense. It was not me doing the measurement, it was only reported to me. But it still leaves me with the question - what to replace it with ?

Comment: You need to do better measurements to confirm, in part that the inductance is 270 nH - test at lower frequencies as well and build up a picture of the impedance across several frequencies. Try and determine the self resonant frequency too.

Comment: If you (the OP) have things like function generators and oscilloscopes, you can measure the inductance by looking at the slope of the current when you apply a voltage square wave. It is a little trouble to set up, but it will reveal if something funny is going on.